# Is it possible to create a font that is in a book?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, font-design

I want to know if it is possible to create a font that replicates the font of a book.

For example, If I want to use the font that is used in the following Image:

[image]

[Link to full PDF](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf)

Is it possible to copy all the alphabet which that style in order to create that font?

Comment: These are already fonts - Helvetica and Times. Your copy is just a poor quality scan.

Answer (score 3):

Is it *possible*? Yes, certainly with a great deal of effort. You would need to separate the glyphs, clean them up, convert them to usable formats (vector), then reconstruct the font in an application such as FontLab.

Now, why anyone would spend tens or hundreds of hours to do such a thing is a mystery. You can purchase the fonts. There's really no need to try and recreate what is already available.

Answer (score 0):

It's done so it can be done again. If you input into Font Squirrel matcherator or other font identification sites few words of the text, you get plenty of good suggestions. Some of them even are detoriated as the text in your PDF.

My advice: get ready fonts. The existence of this question reveals that you do not understand what is a computer font. It's a piece of software which is much more than copied shapes of the characters. Even if you succeed to recreate perfectly the shapes, the result is not any good before an enormous amount of numerical info is added to make the characters sit perfectly positioned in relative each other.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a font that recalls the metal cast press. Try out a font like OldStyle from dafont.com, as long as you don't need to recreate all that maths.